# Where to find good examples or Templates for Configuration Management Plans?

Tags: configuration-management, rup, cmp

Documentation is not the favorite area of a developer but an important area to fulfill if you want to have standards in the organization.  We are trying to put together a new Configuratio Mgmt Plan to setup Change Controls, Backups strategies and other fun things, like the process from development, staging to production.

I will like to have your opinions on good examples or probably a good start for CMP process.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like some list of the item in software configuration management plant, this links provide an example: http://www.scmwise.com/software-configuration-management-plan.html

However, please notes that the content of SCM plan is highly dependent on your company standard and the process during software development itself.

Answer (score 0):

I usually refer [cmcrossroads.com](http://www.cmcrossroads.com) for such information. The site is not organized well but has lots of info. Another very useful resource is [nasa.gov](http://nasa.gov) (I know).

Rather than me listing out the index of a CM plan, I would recommend you to check this link out: http://www.nasa.gov/centers/ivv/pdf/170879main_T2401.pdf

Some quick pointers for setting up CM process:

1. You absolutely need the
   management's/corporation's backing.
   Without them pushing, no one will
   adhere to the process.
2. SCM is like police/postal service. No one remembers them until something goes wrong. In your case, it is a good sign if no one talks (complains) about your implemented SCM process.
3. Open source SCM systems are at par with the other kind. Depending on the intensity of your project, you may have to do several POCs to determine which system suits your needs.

This is a vast topic; I would recommend Alexis Leon's [book](http://tinyurl.com/2rkk33) if you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Software development related all kind of documents are available as part of Rational Unified Process[RUP]. You can find those at:

- [Configuration management Plans](http://sce.uhcl.edu/helm/rationalunifiedprocess/process/artifact/ar_cmpln.htm)
- [RUP templates](http://www.ts.mah.se/RUP/RationalUnifiedProcess/)
- [RUP templates](http://espec.ppgia.pucpr.br/doc/programming/rup/index.htm)